# Docker creates many containers in AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers, amazon-ecs

I’m using AWS ECS. The whole process is automated and everything looks perfect.
However when I ssh to the docker host (amazon linux ami) i notice that there is many containers created from my image instead of just one. What can cause this? Wrong ECS configuration or image with errors or something? See the photo attached.

[image]

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: is this not a case of your containers exiting prematurely? perhaps the container is automatically restarted when it fails

Comment: As you can see your containers are failing and being restarted. Run `docker logs <containerid>` to peek into what happened inside the container

Answer (score 0):

The container you are trying to run exits after ~2 minutes (e.g. created 8 minutes ago, destroyed 6 minutes ago -> 2 minutes runtime). Thus, ECS creates a new container which then again exits with status code `137`.

[This has been discussed here already](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=191472) and is probably caused by insufficient memory or CPU assigned to your container. This also can happen if you created an [Application Load Balancer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html) but the health check fails for some reason.